# Problems importing python modules from other directories?

Tags: python, import, directory

My project has been getting bigger and the correct modules are failing to import properly. Result is the program stops running at the first line. Here is what my directory map currently looks like:

```
PROTOTYPE
- Sound_editor (folder)
- - openant (cloned library from Github)
- - - __init__.py
- - - (a bunch of files and folders from the library)

**
- - - ant
- - - - base
- - - - - ant.py
- - - - - __init__.py
- - - - easy
- - - - - __init__.py
- - - - - node.py
**

- - - demo.py

- - __init__.py
- - editor.py
- - reader.py
- - streamer.py
- - main2.py

- main1.py
```

The problem that I am getting repeatedly, in many different forms is this:
**streamer.py**

```
from editor import A_class
```

**main1.py**

```
import Sound_editor.streamer
```

When I run main1.py, it first imports streamer file. Then the streamer file attempts and fails to import the editor file.
**error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'editor'
```

I don't know what else to do. I've tried:

1. So many things from this guide: https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html
2. variations of dotting my way to the right path: `import PROTOTYPE.Sound_editor.editor`
3. using from: `from Sound_editor import editor` as well as `from Sound_editor.editor import A_class`
4. I've studied this answer: [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder). I'm not sure what he means by structuring directories as a package. I have already added **init**.py files. (They are empty..)

What else should I try. Do you experts see any obvious errors?

**Update 1**
chepner recommends a relative import. `from .editor import A_class`. This was successful but caused another problem that requires expounding.

streamer.py also has the following import: `from .openant.ant.easy.node import Node` but also node has imports too:
**node.py**
`from ant.base.ant import Ant`
**error**
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ant.base'`
On first glance, it seems like the library I cloned from Github has some naming troubles. Folders and files with same names just sounds like a disaster. When I try using a dot here:
```from .ant.base.ant import Ant``
**error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Sound_editor.openant.ant.easy.ant'
```

Either:

1. `from .ant...` is not going up enough directories or
2. The file/folder called ant is confusing the command...??

Answer (score 3):

`from editor import A_class` is an absolute import. Python will *only* look in directories that appear in `sys.path` for a module named `editor`. When you run `main1.py`, `Sound_editor` is found because it's in the same directory as `main1.py`; `editor` is not.

What you want is a relative import, so that `editor` is found in whatever package `streamer` itself is found in:

```
from .editor import A_class
```

Comment: Another related issue emerged down the chain of imports. It's too much info to add here in the comments, so check update1. I also updated the directory I outlined. You got me past the first link in the chain.

Comment: Are there `__init__.py` files missing from the packages, or did you omit them from the question for brevity? For example, without `easy/__init__.py`, `easy` is not a module.

Comment: Very briefly: a package is a module that can (or does; I'm not sure if there is a distinction) contain other modules. A module can be created from a file or a directory containing a `__init__.py` file.

Comment: I omitted /__init__.py for brevity. Just added them to the main post

Comment: And `ant/`? It's not just the "terminal" directory that needs `__init__.py`; *all* directories along the way require them.

Comment: But `from ant.base.ant import Ant` is an absolute import as well, so you are back to the original problem again.

Comment: Correct, __init__.py is included all the way down, but excluded from the top level: PROTOTYPE. 

(next reply) from .ant.base.ant import Ant ---> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Sound_editor.openant.ant.easy.ant'
Which is interesting because we are importing .ant.base.and and it's looking in ant.easy.ant...

Comment: Does `SoundEditor/__init__.py` exist? Seems like it should for `import Sound_Editor.streamer` to work, but it's quite possible I'm misexplaining or misunderstanding something as well.

Comment: `node.py` seems to assume that `openant` itself is on `sys.path`. It should be something like `from ..ant.base.ant import Ant`.

Comment: yes soundeditor has __init__.py. So I just added 3 dots. `from ...ant.base.ant import Ant`

Comment: I think you've helped come down to the fundamental problem here: all of the directories in this library are screwed. I was hoping that there would be a more elegant solution than going into each module to update imports. Also, I expected that a library like this wouldn't have issues like this.

Comment: The solution might be to put `PROTOTYPE/openant` directly into `sys.path`. The library appears to assume it will be installed somewhere already on the path, not embedded in another project.

Comment: So I just updated all the imports. No errors. But I think the sys.path solution might be more sustainable. Should I just follow the other answerer for that?

Comment: I would install the library properly (in a virtual environment), rather than trying to import from an embedded directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235074/discussion-between-michael-korn-and-chepner).

Answer (score 0):

you can add to the Python path at runtime:

## some_file.py

import sys

## insert at 1, 0 is the script path (or '' in REPL)

sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file